# Sublime text 2 : select tags with all content in it

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to select tags and all text between tags, such as:

```
<div> 
Hello World 
</div>
```

Consider above html code when I place cursor between div tags and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> it select all content that is Hello World but not div tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> once while your cursor is in the text, it will select all the text. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> again, and it will select the tags. Keep hitting it, and the selection will keep expanding outwards.

Comment: Awesome! Very useful shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Pretty Useful